# Is there a way to create Algolia query strings that facet on page load?

Tags: algolia

Essentially we have a "dumb" search bar on our website. When the form is submitted, it just sends the user to `/search?q={query}` where our Algolia instantsearch.js resides.

We would like to add a dropdown to that dumb search bar to filter down to Car, Truck, Boat, or Airplane. That value is in our Algolia index as `category` and is facted.

Is documentation available on constructing a query string with facets that Algolia instantsearch.js will pick up? Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

After some more Google-fu I was able to find [this issue on Algolia's Github](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/1506) which had exactly what I needed. Here is the code that worked for us:

```
<form method="GET" action="/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <select name="dFR[category][0]">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">All types</option>
        <option value="Car">Car</option>
        <option value="Truck">Truck</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

If the user doesn't select a type, it will send them to `/search?q={query}`. If the user does select a type, for example "Car", they will be sent to `/search?q={query}&dFR[category][0]=Car` (url encoded of course.)

This applies the proper filter, assuming faceting is setup on `category` and you're using a fairly vanilla implementation of instantsearch.js.